# CCScrollVeiw is not Kinetic Scrolling

Tags: cocos2d-x-2.x

I use CCScrollVeiw but it can't smoothness sroll.

```
scroll_view = new cocos2d::extension::CCScrollView;
```

I use `setViewSize` and `container->setContentSize()` method.
I set same width size.

However I set bigger contentsize's width size than view's.
However I didn't resolve
Could you tell me why non-smoothy scroll?

Comment: not all scroll range.
only bottom are not smooth.

Comment: If I use initWithViewSize, 
scroll_view->initWithViewSize(CCSizeMake(320, -3000));
it looks little good but not enough

Answer (score 0):

CCScrollView* CCScrollView::create(CCSize size, CCNode* container)

your container can be current layer.And size'll be view,which is scrollable.So if u have lesser items to scroll view, decrease view size.And if u have many items to scroll u can increase view size.

i can help you..if u'll be more descriptive....or post code...